# How to extract the index names of a multiindexed dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed dataframe that Looks like this:

```
                                            TQ bought  
HT           Detailed Instrument                   
Alternative     Investments                 359.445000  
Alternative     Investments                 633.670000  
Alternative     Investments                237.970000  
Alternative     Investments                 40.955000
```

HT and Detailed Instrument are the multi-index column names, TQ bought represent the values of the Pivot table.

I'd like to extract the column names of the index as list, such that:

```
idx_headers = ["HT", "Detailed Instrument"]
```

I have tried `df.index.levels` but this does not generate the desired output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `index.names`:

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Alternative'], ['Investments']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
           names=['HT Detailed', 'Instrument'])

print (df.index.names)
['HT Detailed', 'Instrument']
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `df.index.names`.

See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html